# Click button to change CSS in D7

Tags: javascript, theming

I'm trying to create a clickable link that changes the css using jquery. I've tried many approaches and nothing seems to work. Hopefully someone here can push me into the right direction.

Button html (in a block):

```
<a href="#" id="change_css">Change CSS</a>
```

Button code (in change_css.js):

```
(function($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.my_node_toggle = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            $("#change_css", context).click(function(){
                $('a').css({"color":"#ff0"});  
            });
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The script is being loaded, but nothing happens when I click on the link.

Comment: I suggest you put some debug code , like `console.log("click fired correctly");` in click handler function to sure that click handler work correctlty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem resides in the way you are calling the css function in jQuery. Try this, it works for me:

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.my_node_toggle = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $("#change_css", context).click(function() {
        $('a').css("color","#ff0");
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```